# how do you expose a service for remoting?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

**Question**

Is it possible to instantiate `FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener` without the second parameter, `IService`?

**Background**

Service Fabric allows you to expose multiple *remote* endpoints, by which you can query the service from an *external* service. For example, the following code will expose this service via 2 different endpoints:

```
    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext => new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(serviceContext,
                new AccountService(),
                new FabricTransportRemotingListenerSettings
                {
                    EndpointResourceName = "AccountsRemotingListenerEndpoint"
                }), "AccountsRemotingListenerEndpoint"),
            new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext => new OwinCommunicationListener(Startup.ConfigureApp,
                serviceContext, ServiceEventSource.Current, "ServiceEndpointHttps"))
        };
    }
```

**What does this enable us to do
?**

A service that is *external* to `AccountService`, is now able to call `AccountService` methods as if they were local. Example usage would be:

```
    public async Task<AccountModel> GetAccount(Guid id)
    {
        var proxy = ServiceProxy.Create<IAccountService>(new Uri(Client.AccountserviceUrl),
            new ServicePartitionKey(), listenerName: "AccountsRemotingListenerEndpoint");
        var result = await proxy.GetAccount(id);
        var account = new AccountModel
        {
            AccountId = result.AccountId.Value,
            Name = result.Name
        };

        return account;
    }
```

**Digging deeper: why do I want to exclude the IService parameter?**

*I am glad that you asked.*

The service we are trying to expose, is simply an implementation of [SharpReverseProxy](https://github.com/SharpTools/SharpReverseProxy). There is no *service* code in it.

It's just Web API configuration code in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
    IHostingEnvironment env, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {

    app.UseProxy(new List<ProxyRule> {
        new ProxyRule {
            Matcher = uri => uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("/api/"),
            Modifier = (req, user) => {
                var match = Regex.Match(req.RequestUri.AbsolutePath, "/api/(.+)service");
                req.RequestUri = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}.{1}/{2}",
                    match.Groups[1].Value,
                    req.RequestUri.Host,
                    req.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Replace(match.Value, "/api/")
                ));
            },
            RequiresAuthentication = true
        }
    },
    r => {
        _logger.LogDebug($"Proxy: {r.ProxyStatus} Url: {r.OriginalUri} Time: {r.Elapsed}");
        if (r.ProxyStatus == ProxyStatus.Proxied) {
            _logger.LogDebug($"        New Url: {r.ProxiedUri.AbsoluteUri} Status: {r.HttpStatusCode}");
        }
    });
}
```

**Assuming that this code is part of a separate service, how do we expose it via `FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener` in spite of it having no service class?**

Is it possible to instantiate `FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener` without the second parameter, `IService`?

This is on-premises.

Comment: When creating your listener, traditionally you would pass in 'this' (i.e. the service instance created by Service Fabric, in which the endpoint creation code is running), not 'new AccountService()'. I don't think SF would have any knowledge of this new service, and therefore wouldn't be able to manage it.

Comment: ```new AccountService()``` does work indeed, it's in the same project. i've attempted to use ```this``` as you had suggested, but no luck, i've made a screen recording here https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-CBbbTXkYHZo/WpQzF0t74MI/AAAAAAAAE4s/AWGUIHVPhPAMcZgWWc1l76ud002Y4TodACHMYCw/s0/2018-02-26_10-17-02.gif

Comment: You have to implement IService on your service class interface.  (It's just a marker interface, you don't have to implement any methods.)  Something like "internal class AccountService : IAccountService {...}"  and the interface would be "public interface IAccountService : IService {...}"

Comment: Oops I just noticed this code is in your stateless service class (Web).  I'm a little unclear now what you're trying to do. But the fact remains that if you create your service classes yourself, SF won't be able to manage them for you. Usually the idea is you create your public-facing endpoints in one or more stateless services, forming an API. Then pass client calls from stateless into the stateful services.